# Node.js with MongoDB driver - trying to get valid JSON output with quotes around keys

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am very new to Node.js (and only slightly less new at MongoDB) - I am trying to figure out how to produce valid JSON using the native driver.  The code below produces results, but the keys are not enclosed in quotes so my application is choking because it considers it invalid JSON.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
    if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

    var collection = db.collection('blah');

    var query = [
        { $group: {
            _id: {
                month: { $month: "$time" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$time" },
                year: { $year: "$time" },
            },
            rule: { $avg: "$data.rule.avg" }
        } },
        { $sort: { "_id.year": 1, "_id.month": 1, "_id.day": 1 } }
    ];

    collection.aggregate(query, function(err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

This produces a result like:

```
{ _id: { 
        month: 5, day: 16, year: 2014 
    },
    rule: 84 
}
```

The problem is that the keys are not surrounded by quotes.  Is there something I am doing wrong with this?

I have tried various permutations of:

```
console.dir(toJSON(result));
console.dir(printjson(result));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically result coming from mongodb driver, is a javascript object, and not a JSON string. When you do `console.log(result)`, node.js will inspect the object, and tries to print it as a javascript object literal, which doesn't require quotes around keys.

If you want to have a JSON form of the object, just serialize it:

```
var JSONResult = JSON.stringify(result);
console.log(JSONResult)
```